# How to change color of AppBar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  navbar: {
    colorPrimary: "#FFFFFF",
  },
});

const Login = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <AppBar position="sticky" classes={classes.navbar}>
      <Toolbar>
        <h1>Test</h1>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
  );
};
```

Hello I am kind of a beginner to MaterialUI, how can I change the background color of the AppBar?

Answer (score 0):

`<AppBar style={{ background: '#hexcode' }}>` this is the syntax to change the color of the AppBar component. hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

At useStyles, you should use backgroundColor to instead of colorPrimary. You can try my code below.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  navbar: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
  },
});
```